# Camera intent does not work after clicking more than 10 images?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera

I am clicking images from android using camera intent.It opens the native camera app of android phone.I call `onActivityResult` to get the data from camera app.When i try to click more than 10 images continuously then on click of 'ok' button in camera it's not navigating me back to my app but on cancel it does.please tell me how can i get the solution?

**Code**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "DW");

            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            // Create new folder
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy_hhmmssa")
                    .format(new Date());

            // if (component_id != comp_id) { image_paths.clear(); }

            component_id = comp_id;
            String alter_timeStamp = timeStamp.replaceAll("/", "_");
            cam_client_id = client_id;
            cam_sub_client_id = sub_client_id;

            fname = comp_name + "_" + component_id + "_" + alter_timeStamp
                    + ".jpg";

            fname = fname.replaceAll(",", "");
            fname = fname.replaceAll("&", "");
            fname = fname.replaceAll(" ", "_");

            Log.i("SYNC", "fname is ->" + fname);
            temp_image = image = new File(imagesFolder, fname);
            // compress image size

            temp_uri = uri = Uri.fromFile(image);
            file_uri = uri.getPath();

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            context.startActivityForResult(intent, 90);
```

Thanks

Comment: Post the code along with the crash reports from the logcat if the app crashes. Hard to say what might be wrong without these two things.

Comment: when you work on images do not store the image bitmap instead store the  url of images only.

Comment: tell me the issue here